# How to use Pathfinding using SceneKit (3D obstacles)

Tags: swift, scenekit, arkit, path-finding

I'm trying to use Pathfinding in Swift, combining it using ARKit but I can't see any way to use 3D objects from the SceneView as 3D obstacles.

I've tried to convert SCNNodes to SKNodes in order to use nodes from my SceneView with no results:

```swift
let graph = GKObstacleGraph(obstacles: [], bufferRadius: 30.0)
let mazeParentNode = sceneView?.scene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "maze", recursively: true)
var obstacleSceneNodes: [SCNNode] = mazeParentNode?.childNodes ?? []

//From here I would like to get the PolygonObstacles from my 3D Scene.
```

As an example, I'm using this:

```swift
let graph = GKObstacleGraph(obstacles: [], bufferRadius: GameplayConfiguration.TaskBot.pathfindingGraphBufferRadius)
lazy var obstacleSpriteNodes: [SKSpriteNode] = self["world/obstacles/*"] as! [SKSpriteNode]
lazy var polygonObstacles: [GKPolygonObstacle] = SKNode.obstacles(fromNodePhysicsBodies: self.obstacleSpriteNodes)
```

I didn't see any example of this checking Swift documentation. Is anybody working on something similar?

Comment: I've tried to solved this using SpriteKit 2D scenes and use different levels or "floors" and translate the 2D coordinates and the height (the floor) into 3D coordinates using SceneKit, but, I'm sure this is not the right way to use pathfinding in a AR environment using ARKit.